# How to check which image is set in imageview android

Tags: android, events, imageview, onclicklistener, favorite

I have a star image in action bar. When I click on it, then the image should change to ON star. This is working fine. But how to know whether image is at ON state or OFF state.I want something that, if the image is at OFF mode and user taps on ON star, then it should set to ON star image. Initially, the image is set to OFF mode. So for this, I've wrote give line to turn on as user tap on it :

```
v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
```

Guys pls suggest me for OFF mode if star image is already on. I am not getting any idea.

Comment: wouldn't be easier to use a boolean variable for on/off and set image resource according to it.

Comment: you can set tag. when image ON then set TAG ON and when you changed that you can getTag() and comapre to TAG and image respect to tag.

Comment: 1.You can use a toggle Button and set its background to the star image.2.As far as current scenario you can use an integer or boolean flag to detect on or off state.

Answer (score 4):

you can check it easily by setting tag of each image or by comparing there resource
comparision of resource method is shown below:

```
if (regProfile.getDrawable().getConstantState() == 
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ivpic).getConstantState()){             
      Toast.makeText(_con, "Image is ivPic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
} else{
      Toast.makeText(_con, "Image isn't ivPic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct you can achieve the functionality like this.change this code accordingly for image onclick

```
 private Button button;
 public static boolean isclick=false;
 button.setOnClickListener(seathtlistner);
 private View.OnClickListener seathtlistner = new View.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if(isclick){
  button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onstarimage);
}else{
  button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.offstarimage);
}
isclick=!isclick;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tag property.

```
img_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Boolean tag_isOn = (Boolean) v.getTag();

                tag_isOn = !tag_isOn;
                v.setBackgroundResource(tag_isOn ?android.R.drawable.star_big_on:android.R.drawable.star_big_off);


                v.setTag(tag_isOn);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (img_like.getTag() != null && img_like.getTag().toString().equals("red")) {
                        img_like.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
                        img_like.setTag("heart");
                    } else {
                        img_like.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
                        img_like.setTag("red");
                    }`enter code here`
```